# How do you deal with data schema migrations while using Flutter with Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-freezed

I have a model as below:

```dart
// will refer to this as ProfileV1

@freezed
class Profile with _$Profile {
  // stands for anon users in firebase auth
  const factory Profile.anonymous({
    // stands for the id of anon users in firebase auth
    required String id,
  }) = _AnonymousProfile;
  
  // stands for authed users in firebase auth
  const factory Profile.authenticated({
    required String id,
    required String username,
  }) = _AuthenticatedProfile;
  
  factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ProfileFromJson(json);
}
```

And I work on ProfileV1 for a while, I save some documents with this schema to Firestore. However, a while later, I'd like to introduce a new field to `Profile.authenticated` variant as below:

```dart
// will refer to this as ProfileV2

@freezed
class Profile with _$Profile {
  const factory Profile.anonymous({
    required String id,
  }) = _AnonymousProfile;
  
  const factory Profile.authenticated({
    required String id,
    required String username,
    // new field, simple for the sake of simplicity
    required int upvotes,
  }) = _AuthenticatedProfile;
  
  factory Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ProfileFromJson(json);
}
```

Now, if I'd like to get the old ProfileV1 documents I've saved in Firestore, `Profile.fromJson` of ProfileV2 will *probably* throw an error saying "There's no upvotes field on the fetched document." of some sort.

How do you deal with this situation? How do you (preferably, lazily) migrate a data schema to another after you fetch it from Firestore?

---

## Environment

- Flutter 3.3.5
- Dart 2.18.2
- Freezed 2.2.0